# Testacular/Karma: how to reuse browser's tab?

Tags: browser, karma-runner

Each time I re-run Karma, it opens new Chrome window although there is already one on the screen and with the same URL in it.

How to make Karma runner to reuse browser window and if appropriate tab was opened - reuse this tab?

Answer (score 3):

In the config, set

```
browsers = [];
```

Comment: It stopped opening any browser at all.

Comment: It should print out a message like: Karma running at localhost:9876. Open that up with whatever browser you want, and then leave that tab open to reuse it.

Comment: This is NOT a valid answer, this will case NOT to open the browser at all, which is the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line inside the config.set({...}) block:

```
    restartOnFileChange: false,
```

which is a guarantee.

With that line, whenever you save your file/files, the browser will **REFRESH** itself automatically **instead of reopening**.

**Just in case, the following is my complete karma.conf.js file, which is very efficient:**

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
        ],
        client: {
          jasmine: {
            random: false
          },
          clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
            reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false,
        restartOnFileChange: false,
    });
};
```

In the block, I added the following myself:

```
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      },
```

which makes your "it" blocks show in the order the same as they are in your spec file;

and

```
      restartOnFileChange: false,
```

whose function is what you want and I've already mentioned above.

**You can open your code coverage file in src/coverage/index.html of your project.**

**Note: Sometimes chrome doesn't refresh automatically after you save a file/files. You just refresh it manually, and the whole test will restart. Very simple.**

Comment: I presume from your answer that you meant to: `restartOnFileChange: true` actually, anyway, adding my own answer to make things sharp.

Comment: Hi GullerYA, No I mean "restartOnFileChange: false", not "restartOnFileChange: true".

Comment: Well, sorry then, probably my use-case is different or I'm experiencing it differently but: (A) `false` is the default value according to Karma's spec; (B) when `true` it will stop the current execution and will start anew, logically and according to the spec. This second point ensures, that the previous run won't continue to run in other tab, while new tab is opened, but will force the close of the current tab and starting all anew - which is, IMHO the use-case of the question.

Comment: I stated the purpose of the sentence clearly in my post. Actually just in case anything could go wrong, I included my entire karma.conf.js file. I've tested many components with the karma.conf.js showed above, and everything has gone very well.

Answer (score 0):

I've landed here while looked for the same question in a bit different context.

When running tests, there are cases where Karma immediately opens 2 tabs, so that all tests are running twice. Usually this should not be an issue, but in our case that causes some unexpected latencies and sporadic failures.

Indeed, in order to prevent this unwanted behaviour one should add the following to the Karma configuration:

```json
restartOnFileChange: true
```

This, by Karma's spec, is forcing a runner to stop the current execution and start a fresh one, thus effectively reusing the same current tab.

Default behaviour, `restartOnFileChange: false`, causes to start a new execution while the current one is continuing to run, thus effectively producing 2 concurrently running tabs.